# What is the best translation for the term “snack”?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, difference

For instance, would you use: *der Snack, der Imbiss, die Kleinigkeit, der Schnellimbiss, der Happen,* etc.?

And when would you use which term? i.e. for what kind of snack — a snack commercially packaged or one provided at an office?

Comment: It’s a common anglicism, so no real need for a translation.

Comment: None of the correspondents have proposed "naschen". Is it only a verb in German, or can it be used as a noun.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Imbiss*, and especially *Schnellimbiss*, is more likely to be understood as *food stall* when no context is given.

Both words can be applied to the junk food, but as you can guess from the discussion in comments below @HansAdler's answer, this can lead to funny sentences.

> Ich esse einen Imbiss.

is correct and will be understood and, though, it sounds rather like [a monster that devours a snack stall](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/25835/what-is-the-best-translation-for-the-term-snack#comment61435_25838) as @ORMapper mentions in his comment.

In my opinion, *Snack* and *Kleinigkeit* are more appropriate and the words that are used most often nowadays.

*Happen* is indeed used, too; but less frequently. Actually, I associate this word rather with a different context. Consider a mum that is worried about her child that is not eating enough. She might say to her child that they should eat "noch einen Happen".

Long story short: *Snack* and *Kleinigkeit* are the words I'd go with.

Comment: +1 for quoting "Happen".

Answer (score 6):

The best all-round translation is *Imbiss*. All the others only fit in certain situations or are used only in some regions, but I cannot immediately think of a context for *snack* in which *Imbiss* doesn't fit. An alternative that also fits in many cases is *Zwischenmahlzeit (in-between meal)*. It's not as formal as it might appear to English speakers, but it has some semantical restrictions that should be obvious.

As Jan pointed out in a comment, *snack* can refer to potato crisps, salt sticks, pop corn etc., whereas *Imbiss* cannot because it always refers to something more substantial. So in German you have to say something like *Knabberzeug* for everything that doesn't fall on the sandwich side of a dividing line between potato crisps and sandwiches that's roughly in the area of cereal bars.

I think this linguistic difference either reflects different attitudes to food by the different speaker communities, or maybe even causes them. I was quite shocked when I discovered that my daughter's otherwise excellent English nursery served potato crisps as part of a meal (during an excursion). Years earlier I had already been shocked when I first saw an English adult eat crisps for lunch on a bus. These culinary practices are almost unthinkable in most of Europe. (I confess that living in the UK for a few years partially converted me.)

Comment: Note in particular that *Schnellimbiss* means primarily *snadk bar*; it's rarely used for *snack* itself.

Comment: I second @Uwe and I would even go so far to say that my first thought upon reading the sentence "Ich esse einen Imbiss." is the picture of a monster that devours a snack stall.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Yes, for some reason we tend to say "Ich nehme einen Imbiss zu mir" instead of "Ich esse einen Imbiss". While I personally have no problem with applying "Imbiss" to a snack bar, I don't think it's the first thing that would come to my mind - and certainly not in a sentence where it doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Jan: You are absolutely right. That's a use of *snack* I didn't think of.

Comment: +1 for the excurs about crisps. I remember them from my time at an English school for lunch, too.